# gunzip a folder with many files

Tags: shell, gzip

I have a folder with 36,348 files gz files. I want to unzip all of them.

Running:

```
gunzip ./*
```

results in

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gunzip: Argument list too long
```

What's the easiest way to get around this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -type f -exec gunzip {} +
```

This assumes that current directory only contains files that you want to unzip.

Comment: Is there any version of `find` where `find .` doesn't work?

Comment: @Patrick: I don't remember `./filename` can work with gunzip. I have tried and it works. Roll back!

Comment: `find . -type f -iname "*.gz" -exec gunzip {} +` to match only files that end `.gz` ignoring case.

Comment: @richard: `-iname` is not POSIX.

Comment: @richard, for POSIX portability, use `find . -type f -name '*.[gG][zZ]' -exec gunzip {} +`

Answer (score 7):

The limit is in the kernel and is on the cumulative size of the arguments and environment passed to the `execve()` system call used to execute a command. You can split it in several invocations.

To `gunzip` all the `.gz` files in the current directory:

with `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs ./*.gz -- gunzip
```

With `ksh93`:

```
command -x gunzip ./*.gz
```

GNUly:

```
printf '%s\0' *.gz | xargs -r0 gunzip
```

POSIXly (and with `gunzip`):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip {} +
```

(beware that one will also uncompress the hidden `.gz` files)

Or you can raise that limit on some systems. On recent versions of Linux:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
gunzip ./*.gz
```

Comment: Why we need `-r` in GNUly?

Comment: @Gnouc, not needed strictly speaking, except with nullglob. But doesn't harm and it's a good habit to have to use it unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: +1 for explaining why gunzuip *.gz did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way I have found is:

```
gunzip -r .
```

Comment: @don_crissti what is the problem, `gunzip -r` nicely has the expansion done by the gunzip circumventing the bash error. It of course also decompresses any files in subdirs, but since the OP used `./*` subdirs would have led to problems if there were any.

Answer (score 1):

A bit efficient solution would be,

`find $PWD -type f -name "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 gunzip`

But if your find does not have -print0 option and your files/dir does not have space in naming, then you can skip -print0 and -0 arguments.

Comment: You can save the call to `xarg` by using the `-exec {} +` construct of find.

Comment: Yes, but doing exec on every file would take more time, wouldn't it ? I guess usings xargs would be more efficient.

Comment: It will not `exec` the program once for each file, but rather behave much like `xargs` does, this is what the `+` at the end of the line is for.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald okay got it, I was not aware of + option. thanks.

Comment: If your find does not have `-print0`, then upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

A less efficient ( but long-run very flexible ) process is make a batch file:

```
ls | grep .gz | sed -e 's/^/gunzip /' | less
```

shows you what will happen so a simple typo doesn't annihilate your system

```
ls | grep .gz | sed -e 's/^/gunzip /' | bash
```

does it right now

```
ls | grep .gz | sed -e 's/^/gunzip /' > unpack
at 02:00
bash unpack
<ctrl-d>
```

does it overnight

(note this example does not account for spaces in filenames.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gunzip the files to a different directory you can try:

```
$ find <path to gzip files> -type f -name "*.gz" -print | \
xargs -I % sh -c 'echo "gunzip -c % > `basename % .gz`"; \
gunzip -c % > `basename % .gz`'
```

In the example above, the files are gunzipped to the directory where the command is run.